# How position elements with dot for a control system diagram?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want control over the positioning of some elements in the following sample:

```
digraph {
        graph [splines=ortho];

        /* Node customization. */
        node [shape=box];
        join [shape=point];
        set [label="set\npoint"];

        /* Define node levels; driving elements on top, feed back below. */
        { rank = min; set; PID; P1; P2; join; OUT;}
        { rank = max; M1;}

        /* Edges */
        set -> PID -> P1 -> P2;
        P2-> join [arrowhead=none];
        join -> {OUT; M1};
        PID -> M1 [dir=back];
}
```

[image: Control system block diagram]

1. If I add more elements to the M1 rank the edges connect to random points (north/top side).  I would like to keep them connect horizontally.  Can this be done?
2. How can I increase spacing (edge length) between **PID**/**P1**/**P2**?
3. It would be nice to align **P1**/**M1** vertically.  Can this be done?
4. <strike>Traditional control system diagrams don't have the **join** node and an edge just comes out of another edge.  Is this possible?</strike>  I removed the arrow head for this.

Maybe some of the questions are extraneous as proper positioning of one will make the others happen naturally.

Comment: [A similar diagram](https://circuitdigest.com/sites/default/files/inlineimages/u/Open-and-Closed-loop-system-for-controllers.png)... I guess I can just use a different arrow head (none) for the 'P2' to join node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generally you can control the point where the arrow enters node with [headport](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport) attribute. But with `ortho` splines this rarely works. Ortho splines live their own life and can cause a variety of different problems, including disappearing edge labels. So there's no definite answer to your first question, each situation has to be handled specifically.
2. You can increase distance between **all** nodes by setting a [nodesep](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:nodesep) graph attribute. But if you need to increase distance only between specific nodes, you can use a trick: Add a label with big number of spaces for value.
3. You can accomplish it with invisible edges.

Points 2 and 3 illustrated in edited example below:

```
digraph {
        graph [splines=ortho];

        /* Node customization. */
        node [shape=box];
        join [shape=point];
        set [label="set\npoint"];

        /* Define node levels; driving elements on top, feed back below. */
        { rank = min; set; PID; P1; P2; join; OUT;}
        { rank = max; M1;}

        /* Edges */
        set -> PID;
        P2-> join [arrowhead=none];
        join -> {OUT; M1}
        PID -> M1 [dir=back];


        PID -> P1 -> P2 [label="               "] /* #2 increase space between specific nodes */
        P1 -> M1 [style=invis] /* #3 align P1 an M1 */
}
```

result:

[image: example]